# SideMenuBar dont load

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a `sidebar` menu made with a `tableview`. When the user click on one cell from the `sidebar`, it shows a `tableview` with categories (check image below). The problem i'm facing is that I click on a cell from the `sidebar` and it loads the right `viewcontroller`, but if I click again it does not load, it simply knows that the column is the same one, it does nothing.

I think its a problem in the `sidebar` that do not load the content because it knows its the same `indexPath`. No? Thank you

**Screen**:

[image]

**My Sidebar code:**

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var opcoesSideMenu: [String] =     ["Inicio","Perfil","Restaurantes","Categorias","Meu Restaurante","Sair"]

class MyMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var selectedMenuItem : Int = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Customize apperance of table view
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0, 0, 0) //
    tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.scrollsToTop = false

    // Preserve selection between presentations
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedMenuItem, inSection: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .Middle)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return opcoesSideMenu.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellmenu") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellmenu")
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.frame.size.width, cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView
    }

 //   cell!.textLabel?.text = "ViewController #\(indexPath.row+1)"


    cell!.textLabel?.text = opcoesSideMenu[indexPath.row] as String

    if cell!.textLabel?.text == "Meu Restaurante" {

        if localizacaoActualizada.temRestaurante == false {

  //  cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x303E73)
        }

    }


    //Vai procurar uma imagem com o mesmo nome que o que esta no array OpcoesSideMenu e colocado ao lado do texto
    var imageName = UIImage(named: opcoesSideMenu[indexPath.row])
    cell!.imageView?.image = imageName



    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

    if localizacaoActualizada.temRestaurante == false {
    if indexPath.row == 4 {return nil}
    }


    return indexPath

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("Selected row: \(indexPath.row)")

    if (indexPath.row == selectedMenuItem) {
        return
    }


    selectedMenuItem = indexPath.row

    //Present new view controller
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
    var destViewController : UIViewController
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("listarRestaurantes") as! UIViewController
        break
    case 1:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("perfilUtilizador")as! UIViewController
        break
    case 2:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("categorias")as! UIViewController
        break
    case 3:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("perfilRestaurante")as! UIViewController

        break
    case 4:
        PFUser.logOut()
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! UIViewController
        break
    default:
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Inicio") as! UIViewController


        break
    }



    sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destViewController)
}
```

}

Comment: Does it call `println("Selected row: \(indexPath.row)")` after a tap?

Comment: The second tap? Yes.